# Applying Gauss-Jordan Inversion in CUDA

Tags: matrix, cuda, inverse, pycuda

I am trying to apply a matrix inverse to a given matrix, but the kernel only works for matrices up to 5x5.

If I use any matrix bigger in dimension, The results are incorrect.

```
mod1 = SourceModule("""
__global__ void invert(float* A, float* I, int n) {
    int tx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int ty = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int col = i * n + ty;
        int row = tx * n + i; 
        if (tx == i) {
            I[tx * n + ty] /= A[i * n + i];
            A[tx * n + ty] /= A[i * n + i];
        }
        if (tx != i) {
            I[tx * n + ty] -= I[col] * A[row];
            A[tx * n + ty] -= A[col] * A[row];
        }
    }
}"""
)
```

Comment: Can you show the main program that calls that kernel?

Answer (score 2):

The code is not correct to make inverse of matrix, you can't calculate all elements of `I` in parallel. I am even amazed that it worked for matrices up to 5x5. The correct solution is to consider the rows of the matrix one by one from first to last in series, divide the row in both matrices by the diagonal element in `A`, then subtract it from all following rows after multiplying it with the element of each row that under the diagonal element, you can do this step in parallel. Finally, after finishing this for all rows, do the same thing backward from last row to first row, this code can clarify this to you:

```
void inverse(float* A, float* I, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    size_t size;
    float v;
    float * d_A, * d_I, * d_v;
    size = (unsigned __int64)n * n * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_A, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc(&d_I, size);
    cudaMalloc(&d_v, sizeof(float));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        I[i * n + i] = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        GetVal<<<1, 1>>>(d_A, i * (n + 1), d_v); \\ Get value of diagonal element
        cudaMemcpy(&v, d_v, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        if (i != n - 1)  \\ Divide row in A matrix starting from element after diagonal
            DivideRow<<<1, n - i - 1>>>(d_A, i * (n + 1) + 1, n - i - 1, v);
        DivideRow<<<1, n>>>(d_I, i * n, n, v);  \\ Divide row in I matrix
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if (i != n - 1)  \\ Subtracting rows
        {
            dim3 GridA(1, 1);
            dim3 BlockA(n - i - 1, n - i - 1);
            dim3 GridI(1, 1);
            dim3 BlockI(n - i - 1, n);
            ModifyRow<<<GridA, BlockA>>>(d_A, i, i, i + 1, n - i - 1, n - i - 1);
            ModifyRow<<<GridI, BlockI>>>(d_A, n, i, i, d_I, i + 1, 0, n - i - 1, n);
            cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        }
    }
    cudaFree(d_v);
    for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)  \\ Backward subtraction
    {
        dim3 GridI(1, 1);
        dim3 BlockI(i, n);
        ModifyRow<<<GridI, BlockI>>>(d_A, n, i, i, d_I, 0, 0, i, n);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
    cudaMemcpy(I, d_I, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_I);
}

__global__ void GetVal(float* A, int p, float* v)
{
    v[0] = A[p];
}

__global__ void DivideRow(float* A, int s, int n, floatd)
{
    int c;
    c = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (c < n)
        A[s + c] /= d;
}

__global__ void ModifyRow(float* MM, int n, int fr, int fc, float* A, int sr, int sc, int nr, int nc)
{
    int r, c, nA;
    r = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (r >= nr)
        return;
    c = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (c >= nc)
        return;
    nA = sc + nc;
    A[(sr + r) * nA + sc + c] -= MM[(sr + r) * n + fc] * A[fr * nA + sc + c];
}
```

Just be careful that the maximum block size is 1024, so if your matrix is larger than 32x32, you will have to modify grid and block sizes.

Comment: Hi, since I am using Pycuda, separate kernel launches take a long time. Do you know If there is a way I can invert a matrix by only using one defined global function?. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only way as I know, you can't create the inverse with one kernel only.